# What does this Python code mean?

Tags: python, python-datamodel

```
__author__="Sergio.Tapia"
__date__ ="$18-10-2010 12:03:29 PM$"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello")
    print(__author__)
```

Where does it get `__main__` and `__name__`?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `__name__` variable is made available by the runtime. It's the name of the current module, the name under which it was imported. `"__main__"` is a string. It's not special, it's just a string. It also happens to be the name of the main script when it is executed.

The `if __name__ == "__main__":` mechanism is the common way of doing something when a .py file is executed directly, but not when it is imported as a module.

Comment: Google Hit #4: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts.  Completely documented in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Python modules can also be run as standalone scripts.  As such, code within the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block will only run if the module is executed as the "main" file.

*Example*:

```
#foo.py
def msg():
    print("bar")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    msg()
```

Running this module will output

```
$ python foo.py
bar
```

where as importing it will output nothing.

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.msg()
bar
```

[Reference](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts)